# When I am closing Codeblocks I am facing this error

Tags: 20.04, error-handling, code-blocks

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I get this error message when closing Codeblocks.

```
Could not save config file '/home/santo/.config/codeblocks.default.conf'!
```

[image]

Comment: Have you enough free disk space? Can you please run codeblocks from terminal and post more error messages you see there (if there exist more)?

Comment: Yeah I have enough disk space and there is no other error.. I have seen that the default.conf file has permission to the root only . Is this why it is happening?

Comment: OK ,run ```sudo chown -R youruser  ~/.config/codeblocks```.Looks like you had opened it as root at least once before.

Comment: thank you very much..  now it is solved

Comment: You're welcome.And if my answer below is helpful please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the owner of the config file is `root` that means that you had opened **CodeBlocks** as root the first time you launched it.So just change the owner of that file(the whole directory in the command below because there might be some other files with that issue):

```
sudo chown -R yourusername  ~/.config/codeblocks
```

`-R` means **Recursive**